# JavaScript forEach()

Tags: javascript, foreach

As I'm learning the forEach() method in JavaScript, I have several questions related to it.
Currently I've written the following piece of code:

```
 var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
 arr.forEach(function(elem, idx, arr){
     elem=elem*2;
 });

 alert(arr); // "1,2,3,4,5,6"
```

My goal is to simply multiply each element in arr by 2, however when I use alert to examine the final values it seems that values inside arr hasn't been modified. What's the problem here?

Also I'm a little confused about the 3 arguments that forEach's function takes. First, is it required to pass in 3 arguments? What will happen if one doesn't provide exactly 3 arguments? Some tutorials I've looked at seem to provide only 1 argument, yet the explanation wasn't clear. Second, do the names of arguments matter (e.g.  e, elem, or element)?

Thank you.

Comment: You're just assigning to the `elem` variable, which is local to the callback. If you want to create a new array, you should use `map` instead of `forEach`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rdxqv909/ just use map for such a scope.

Comment: `forEach` takes only one argument - the callback function (and it takes a second optional one, but lets ignore that for now). The callback function is always called with 3 arguments, but how many parameters it takes (has declared) or how they are named doesn't matter to `forEach` - just like for any regular function in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your approach

You are not assigning new value to anything else but the `elem`, which is only in callback's scope. Modify your code, so that the `elem * 2` is assigned to `arr[idx]`. Working example:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

arr.forEach(function(elem, idx) {
  arr[idx] = elem * 2;
});

document.body.textContent = arr;
```

---

### Better approach

For tasks like that however, you should use **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

arr = arr.map(function(num) {
  return num * 2;
});

document.body.textContent = arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is not getting modified cus you are not modifying it. To do that update the code as following.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
arr.forEach(function(elem, idx, arr){
  arr[idx] = elem*2
});

console.log(arr);
```

If you check the console you would see the updated arr.

Answer (score 0):

1. you cannot edit the array in place by returning the new value or changing `elem`. You can however use the `idx` variable like `arr[idx] = elem * 3` or  use the `map` function.
2. you can omit the parameters that you don't need
3. you can name them whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

For first problem, just use `map`

```
 var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
 arr = arr.map(function(elem){
     return elem*2;
 });

 alert(arr); // "2,4,6,8,10,12"
```

`arguments` is optional, and names doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score -1):

The arguments are optional.

idx lets you know the index of the array element you are currently evaluating.

arr, is the array you are evaluating.

so elem == arr[idx]